# Openerp 7 is passing text to db ids

Tags: python, openerp-7

i have a current problem which i don't understand. The problem is occuring in creating a supplier order. The user is passing products, which calls "onchange_product_id" in class openerp-server/addons/purchase/purchase.py. Within this method, it calls method name_get of class product.product (file openerp-server/addons/product/product.py) to get the supplier set product name.

The onchange method looks as follows

```
def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, pricelist_id, product_id, qty, uom_id,
        partner_id, date_order=False, fiscal_position_id=False, date_planned=False,
        name=False, price_unit=False, context=None):
    ....
    dummy, name = self.pool.get('product.product').name_get(cr, uid, product_id, context=context_partner)[0]
```

After a few lines within name_get (in model product.product) the following code gets executed

```
for product in self.browse(cr, user, ids, context=context):
    sellers = partner_ids and filter(lambda x: x.name.id in partner_ids, product.seller_ids) or []
```

and this throwed an uncaught exception as following

```
openerp.sql_db: bad query: SELECT product_product."product_tmpl_id",product_product.id FROM "product_product" WHERE product_product.id IN ('Allzweckreiniger', 13484) ORDER BY default_code,name_template
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "Allzweckreiniger"
LINE 1: ...OM "product_product" WHERE product_product.id IN ('All...
```

i'm not the python geek, but i'm used to it, so please don't start with beginner guides, as long as it is not specifying my problem.

i have four question regarding the above:

- How did openerp managed to pass the product_product.name "Allzweckreiniger" to the database id field ? 13484 is the right corresponding id of the dataset, so both values get passed
- The uncaught exception happens in the seller line, not the browse. What is causing a select on product_product in the seller line ?
- Why is it happening there and not in the browse as my understanding was till now, that a browse already resolves all *many* relations directly
- And last: The given product has no supplier set in table product.supplierinfo, why is it db accessing at this point at all ?

The problem happened twice on the same product and same order within a few minutes at a customer of mine and then never again. I didn't find the time to talk to the person directly so this is all i currently have. Sadly i couldn't reproduce this at all.

As the filter only reduces the product.supplierinfo datasets to a single dataset matching the current supplier, if present, i currently changed the code to the following to avoid any additional selects in background

```
for product in self.browse(cr, user, ids, context=context):
    sellers = self.pool['product.supplierinfo'].search(cr, user, [('product_id', '=', product.product_tmpl_id.id), ('name', 'in', partner_ids)], context=context)
    for seller in sellers:
        s = self.pool['product.supplierinfo'].browse(cr, user, seller, context=context)
```

My main concern is understanding what causes the wrong select.

Thanks for any help

---

update 10.06.2018:

i digged a little further but it is still odd. The following log is written at the occurence of the uncaught exception and it happened with a few more products. All products have no seller_ids set.

```
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-server/addons/purchase/purchase.py", line 1011, in onchange_product_id
  dummy, name = product_product.name_get(cr, uid, product_id, context=context_partner)[0]
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-server/addons/product/product.py", line 671, in name_get
  sellers = partner_ids and filter(lambda x: x.name.id in partner_ids, product.seller_ids) or []
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 503, in __getattr__
  return self[name]
```

so it seems to reduce on a problem with the filter function. But why is it even executing the left lambda part ? Shouldn't the right product.seller_ids be just an empty list ?

And why is it then dumping on product_product model while accessing the product_supplierinfo ?

Comment: Where does `ids` come from?

Comment: thanks for the edit. I updated the question, ids is passed from the onchange method and properly filled with a single product_product db id, in my case set to 13484, which i already checked to be properly set with a except_osv

Comment: i got it solved and at the same momemt, i'm very confused. Openerp is passing lists to the parameters product_id and uom_id to the method onchange_product_id, containing the db id and the result of name_get of the corresponding field. e.g. it is passing [13484, 'Allzweckreiniger'] to the product id, causing the problem. i workarounded it now, checking for a list in the parameter, filter out all not integer values and overwriting product id with the first integer value found. But it feels very wrong doing this. In my opinion, this has to happen with every onchange method if it fails here.